# dbt trigger a full refresh that cascades downstream to all other models in the pipeline?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, etl, refresh, dbt

Say that I have 2 models, where the second depends on the first. The first is an incremental model, while the second materializes as a table.

Is there a way to run/test/build the second model with the --full-refresh tag, so that the first incremental table is refreshed as well?

This is the command I'm running

```
clear && dbt run --full-refresh --select models/folder/my_model.sql+ --profiles-dir .
```

I've seen in the docs and elsewhere that adding the `+` at the end of the model path should cascade the full refresh, but i'm not seeing it actually happen. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You were very close:
the `+` operator works the following way: "If placed at the front of the model selector, `+` will select all parents of the selected model" (see docs https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/node-selection/graph-operators#the-plus-operator).

You are putting your operator at the end of your model name:
`models/folder/my_model.sql+`

Meaning that you will only run all *child* models of `my_model`.

Therefore, I believe that placing the `+` operator in front, in order to run all parent models of `my_model`, would solve your issue:

`dbt run --full-refresh --select +my_model --profiles-dir .`

If you then also wanted to run all child models of `my_model`, you could place another `+` operator at the end:

`dbt run --full-refresh --select +my_model+ --profiles-dir .`